# How to get if else statement in mysql query in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

There is I am doing mistake in my mysql query. can anyone help me out??

```
select * from user_errors where user_id = '2' 
IF( type = 'custom_type' ) second_user_id != '2' ELSE second_user_id = '2' 
END IF
```

Comment: post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no necessary to use `if else`, anyway try this;)

```
select * from user_errors
where user_id = '2'
and ((type = 'custom_type' and second_user_id != '2') or second_user_id = '2')
```

Or you must use it, try this;)

```
select * from user_errors
where user_id = '2'
and case when type = 'custom_type' then second_user_id != '2' else second_user_id = '2' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this( You don't need to use if else condition)

```
select * from user_errors where user_id = '2'
and ((type = 'custom_type' and second_user_id != '2') 
or (type != 'custom_type' and second_user_id = '2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from user_errors 
where user_id = '2' 
IF(type = 'custom_type', second_user_id != '2', second_user_id = '2' )
```

Comment: You should have pointed out the difference between the `IF()` function which you are using and the `IF` `THEN` `END IF` statement which OP tried to use as MySQL supports both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_errors
WHERE user_id = '2'AND  ( case when type = 'custom_type' then second_user_id != '2' else second_user_id = '2' end)
```